# Hive Admin not working after enabling Sentry and no kerberos set

Tags: hive, apache-sentry

I need your help in resolving an issue related to Hive Permission. I have enabled Sentry in CDH 5.5 environment but Kerberos is not sent. I could not able to create roles or grant permission to hive objects. For every access need to login through root and sudo to hive and access the object.

When i try su to hive from hdfs user and try giving below command

> set role admin;

FAILED: SemanticException The current builtin authorization in Hive is incomplete and disabled.

Please suggest me how to resolve this.

Thanks & Regards